# libc.h: No such file or directory when compiling nanomsg pipeline sample

Tags: c, libc, nanomsg

Trying to get a simple nanomsg file running, starting with the first one here: https://github.com/dysinger/nanomsg-examples

Installed nanomsg to `/usr/local/lib/nanomsg-0.2-alpha`. Ran `sudo ./configure`, `sudo make check`, `sudo make install` and `sudo ldconfig` as the [instructions said](http://nanomsg.org/download.html). All tests pass.

When I run it says libc.h is not found:

```
$ gcc pipeline.c /usr/local/lib/libnanomsg.a -o pipeline
pipeline.c:2:18: fatal error: libc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What is libc.h? I haven't done any C programming since college. Is it part of nanomsg or a C library?

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Libc.h just contains small list of includes. To compile nanomsg sample its enough to ([src](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.nanomsg/1188)):

Replacing:

```
#include <libc.h>
```

with

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
```

I used this cmd for static compilation:

```
gcc -pthread bus.c ../nanomsg/.libs/libnanomsg.a -o test -lanl
```

Note -pthread and -lanl at the end of line.

Comment: This worked well, however note that I needed to run `./configure --enable-static` when building nanomsg to get this to work properly, otherwise there were missing symbols in libnanomsg.a.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate libc.h
```

find the path where `libc.h` located. eg, if your `libc.h` is `/usr/local/include`

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include pipeline.c /usr/local/lib/libnanomsg.a -o pipeline
```

Comment: Well, that helped but now I've got a bunch of these: `/usr/local/go/include/../src/lib9/utf/utf.h:46:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token` and so on.